# How to find the selected radion button on page load using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I have a list that have radion button in each `<li>`

```
<ul class="woof_childs_list">

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="woof_514" class="woof_radio_term woof_radio_term_514" data-term-id="514" name="product_cat" value="514">
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="woof_515" class="woof_radio_term woof_radio_term_515" data-term-id="515" name="product_cat" value="515">
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="woof_516" class="woof_radio_term woof_radio_term_516" data-term-id="516" name="product_cat" value="516">
    </li>

    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="woof_517" class="woof_radio_term woof_radio_term_517" data-term-id="517" name="product_cat" value="517">
    </li>

</ul>
```

There are instances that one of the buttons are selected when the page will load.

I want to find and unselect or uncheck the selected radio button on page load for my preference.

My current code looks like this:

```
  var j = jQuery.noConflict();
  if(j('.woof_childs_list > li > .woof_radio_term').is(':checked')) {
     j(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
```

The problem with my code above is that I am not able to capture the selected radio button on page load..

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: `uncheck the selected radio button on page load for my preference` - You mean while page loading or after the page loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prop` method.In this demo one of the input is default checked and this

```
$("input[name='product_cat']").prop('checked',false)
```

will unchecked it.Also remember to put the code inside document.ready or load script after dom has been loaded

```js
$("input[name='product_cat']").prop('checked', false)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="woof_childs_list">

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="woof_514" class="woof_radio_term woof_radio_term_514" data-term-id="514" name="product_cat" value="514">
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="woof_515" class="woof_radio_term woof_radio_term_515" data-term-id="515" name="product_cat" value="515" checked>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="woof_516" class="woof_radio_term woof_radio_term_516" data-term-id="516" name="product_cat" value="516">
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="woof_517" class="woof_radio_term woof_radio_term_517" data-term-id="517" name="product_cat" value="517">
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try  this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.woof_childs_list input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code from:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
if(j('.woof_childs_list > li > .woof_radio_term').is(':checked')) {
   j(this).prop('checked', false);
}
```

to:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j('.woof_childs_list > li > .woof_radio_term:checked').prop('checked', false);
```

You get all checked with `.woof_radio_term:checked`.